# I want to draw the icon in the calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I want create a calendar. This is how it works:
1. Today when you click to bring up other activity.

1. Activity is do something. Then press submit.
2. New dialog box appears. In this dialog, chooses one of two icons.
3. Painted on the calendar icon of your choice. (This icon 'today' only painted.)

i have try, but it painting all of gridView.

http://caughtinthemobileweb.files.wordpress.com/2011/06/calendarview.png

↑This image is just the shape I want. how can i do that?

Comment: you must use CustomAdapter for your gridview to control when ImageView show an icon.

Comment: I need an example to understand your explanation. ex, Different sources using a custom adapter.... etc..

Answer (score 0):

this is my example:

```
public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
String[] IDs = { "1", "2", "3" };
String[] Names = { "Ali", "Mohsen", "Javad" };
String[] Familys = { "Taghavi", "Hoseini", "Rezaei" };
int[] Images = { R.drawable.book_icon, R.drawable.music_icon,
        R.drawable.photo_icon };
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tvID;
    TextView tvName;
    TextView tvFamily;
    ImageView ivMain;

}

public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context, String[] iDs, String[] names,
        String[] familys) {
    super();
    IDs = iDs;
    Names = names;
    Familys = familys;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return IDs.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder viewholder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewholder = new ViewHolder();
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_row, parent, false);
        viewholder.tvID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvID);
        viewholder.tvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvName);
        viewholder.tvFamily = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvFamily);
        viewholder.ivMain = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivMain);
    } else {
        viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewholder.tvID.setText(IDs[position]);
    viewholder.tvName.setText(Names[position]);
    viewholder.tvFamily.setText(Familys[position]);
    viewholder.ivMain.setImageResource(Images[position]);
    convertView.setTag(viewholder);
    return convertView;
}
```

}

You have to specific your icon in getView method. This Line is for specific your icon:

```
viewholder.ivMain.setImageResource(Images[position]);
```

You can use it in other way for example according to the number of cell that here is position.